# How to limit (Queue) the number of threads executing against a given db (Separate data for each concurrent test)?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have constructed an automation framework which executes test suites concurrently.

Currently if my DB command is executed by multiple threads (Tests) at the same time, the data is incorrect.

I have tried to use static, synchronized etc with no luck, any ideas?

Example code:

```
public static synchronized String createAccount() throws IOException, SQLException {
    DbManager.createDatabaseConnection();
    DbManager.executeSqlUpdateStatement(Account_Creation_Scripts.createAccount_Sql_Command());
    account_pojo.setAccountEmail(locateMostRecentlyCreatedAccount());
    LoggerInstance.log("Account created: " + account_pojo.getUniEmail());
    DbManager.closeDatabaseConnection();
    return tutor_pojo.getAccountEmail();
}
```

If I run the code using x1 thread instance, each test will create and extract the correct accounts from the db etc.

Please note:

- No Exceptions occur.
- The issue only occurs when running more than one thread concurrently, for example:

> ```
> test1 = uses account: email1@email.com
> test2 = uses account: email2@email.com
> test3 = uses account: email3@email.com
> test4 = uses account: email3@email.com
> ```

As you can see both test3 and 4 are using the same email address, even though email1-4@email.com are visible within the database.

Comment: "the data is incorrect" means your DB is buggy or you use it in wrong way. Multiple clients can only make DB to respond slow, not incorrect. So first find out real reason, and then limit the number of clients, otherwise  it may happen, that with little number of clients incorrect behavour will demonstrate less frequently, your test pass, but later incorrectness appear again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about making your tests transactional and choose correct transaction isolation.
What happens in your test is that Thread4 creates account, then Thread3 creates account after that both threads try to select the most recently created and get the same value.

Also you do not control your input here.
You might need to change your code to accept some parameters in `createAccountMethod` in that case each of your tests can use separate hardcoded e-mail.

Comment: thanks for your message @Ivan, 'Thread4 creates account, then Thread3 creates account after that both threads try to select the most recently created and get the same value.' is spot on, do you think adding a randomised Thread.sleep() to the method could be a potential solution? then each thread instance would randomly sleep before triggering the method

Comment: As I've said you either need to use transactions so that one thread will not see database changes made by another or you need to provide emails as arguments and not rely on database to generate them